# Cakephp URL parameter retrieving ()

Tags: cakephp-2.0, parameter-passing, response, payment

How can I retrieve the responsekey from a payment site using my cakephp controller?

The major issue is that I'm receiving a response key from the payment integration site with special charaters like `\ /+%&`, etc.
While executing a link like the following, I get a 'page not found' error.

**domain.com/Controller/action/reskey:IXcJUEkT//rGWiqllgOmJcw1P1CW362ZMAkoSMPHM+SMppkWVKzxLg+/m1VNUAKwrQ1+lfcJkQEnyp0nb/+D1ur**

How can I get the response key as a passed argument in my controller function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function key(){ //change the key action name yo your action

     //$this->params->url will result to domain.com/Controller/action/reskey:IXcJUEkT//rGWiqllgOmJcw1P1CW362ZMAkoSMPHM+SMppkWVKzxLg+/m1VNUAKwrQ1+lfcJkQEnyp0nb/+D1ur

    list($url,$reskey) = split(":",$this->params->url); //split via ":"
    debug($reskey); //returns to 'IXcJUEkT//rGWiqllgOmJcw1P1CW362ZMAkoSMPHM+SMppkWVKzxLg+/m1VNUAKwrQ1+lfcJkQEnyp0nb/+D1ur'
    exit;
}
```